# Using reflection to find class member value

Tags: java, reflection

Im using reflection to find class member and their related type with the following code,
but my question is if there is a way to find class default value ?
For example in this case i need the value **1L**.

```
public class SalesOrrP implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialUID = 1L;
}
```

I have used the following code to find member name and type

```
Field[] declaredFields = clsObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : declaredFields) {
    // Get member name & types
    Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
    Type genericType = field.getGenericType();
    String fieldTypeName = fieldType.getName();
    String memberName = field.getName();
    if (genericType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) genericType;
        for (Type typeOfReferance : pt.getActualTypeArguments()) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably obvious answer, but: is it possible that the field does not hold its initialised value (i.e. it has been changed post-initialisation)?

Comment: Maybe you coult create another instance of the class and look up the value there?

Comment: @assylias - not sure what do you mean...

Comment: @ keuleJ - could you provide any example

Comment: @JeanTennie Do you have some code that uses reflection to change the value of the final field? If not then the field will always have its initial value (1L in your example).

Comment: yes I have latter on field.set(newInstance, fieldValue);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static fields, you don't need to create a new instance. In your case, `SalesOrrP.class.getDeclaredField("serialUID").get(null)` should be enough.

For non static fields, you can't get the *initialization value* you're talking about, since it is automatically relocated by the compiler within the constructor of the class. It means that you have to create a new instance of the class to get the value you're looking for.

If you're sure the classes provide a nullary constructor (i.e. a constructor with no argument), here is what you could do:

```
public static <T> Map<String, Object> getDefaultValues(Class<T> clazz, T instance) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> defaultValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = clazz.newInstance();
    }
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object defaultValue = field.get(instance);
        defaultValues.put(field.getName(), defaultValue);
    }
    return defaultValues;
}
```

For example, in your case, `getDefaultValues(SalesOrrP.class, null)` will return `{serialUID=1}`. If you already have an instance of your class, give it as a 2nd argument (instead of `null` in the above example).

Comment: but how can i get the value ,Im already create instance of the class and from it Im calling to the fields

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to access the value of the field, you simply need to make it accessible and get the value:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
long value = field.getLong(null);
```

Comment: Hi , but I cant use it since here you assume that the field is type long but i need general solution to find if any member type have value assigned to it...

Comment: also for example if member is like private String myVlaue = "156";I was tried to use      Object object = field.get(null);
     
     String string = object.toString(); but it works for the first member type l but if i have string etc i got dump

Comment: @JeanTennie I don't understand what you mean - if you don't know the type of the field, you can use `field.get(null);` as you said. If you know it is of a specific type, you can cast it to that type: `SomeType s = (SomeType) field.get(null);`.

Comment: I know just the type name ,i.e. string with the type name

Comment: You can get the class with `Class.forName` but you won't be able to create a variable of that type explicitly... Instead of explaining what you are trying, you should explain why you want to do this as there might be a different way.

Answer (score -1):

This final value can be changed with reflection only.
If you know that reflection  can't be used, you're safe.

If not, you can create a new instance and get the new instance's value.

Comment: final values can be changed through reflection

Comment: in this case its final but in other cases the member can have value and i want to identify it...